# See if a window loses focus

Tags: java, swing, jframe, focus

I have an undecorated `JFrame` with my own 'header' at the top. It works fine except for telling if the window is out of focus.

I've tried things like

```
if(!frame.hasFocus()
    //Do stuff here
```

But this obviously won't work when I have other components in the window, such as a `JTextField`. I haven't found a way to do this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) Why is it that  the frame should only `Do stuff here` if the frame has focus? BTW - it helps to form & ask a specific question. What is your question?

Comment: @AndrewThompson it doesn't `Do stuff` when the frame is focused, it should only do something if the frame/window doesn't have focus

Comment: Well ..duh! That much was always obvious. My question is ***why***? (You're still describing ***what***.)

Comment: I'm also curious as to why, but a quick Google found [Java Window Focus Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html), which might help you out.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Visuals and timers mainly. If I know the window is out of focus I can turn off most of the timers and things

Comment: @markspace that worked for me! Thank you very much, I was unaware that there was a FocusListener and it is very useful knowing there is one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code by which you can implement it:

```
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowFocusListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class SwingTest {

public static void main(String args[])
{ 
    swing();
}
public static void swing()
{
    JFrame g= new JFrame("First");
    g.setVisible(true);
    g.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    g.setSize(300, 300);
    g.setLayout(null);
    JLabel l=new JLabel("Times Windows Lost Focus : 0");
    l.setBounds(20,10, 200, 60);
    g.add(l);

    g.addWindowFocusListener( new WindowFocusListener() {
        int c=0;
        @Override
        public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
            c++;


        }

        @Override
        public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
            l.setText("Times Windows Lost Focus :"+c);
            //System.out.println(c);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });;
}
}
```